SQLite 'NativeDatabase.prepareAsync' has been rejected
I am trying to find a record based on the following code,
await userDb.getFirstAsync(query);

But I am getting the following error randomly,
\[Error: Call to function 'NativeDatabase.prepareAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: The 2nd argument cannot be cast to type expo.modules.sqlite.NativeStatement (received class java.lang.Integer)
→ Caused by: Cannot use shared object that was already released\]

The error does not occur every time with the same code. The issue happened randomly. Can someone please help me to figure out what am I doing wrong here?
